# TFS Build, don't add the BUILD Name to Globallist

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, tfs-workitem

Hello
Is there a way to stop TFSBUILD from adding the buildID/BuildName to the Globallist
 "Builds - Myprojectname" ?

Reason, we have a CI Build, and i don't want this type of build to be seen in the list 
"Found in:" in the BUG Workitem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It adds all the Builds under that Team Project to the Globallist irrespective of the BuildDefination. The Manual Workaroud is to delete these builds by editing the global list.
You can also check this blog post for another workaround: 
http://readcommit.blogspot.com/2008/04/found-in-build-team-build-list-make-it.html